# How to automatically navigate to default found tag?

Tags: elisp

I'm trying to slightly enhance the find-tag function by always navigating to the default found tag.

As find-tag is, when I press M-. while the cursor being on a function name, emacs prints the following message:
Find tag (default fun_name):

And it waits for me to either press RET or go to another match. The thing is, I always press RET. So I just would like to skip that step by making emacs "press RET" automatically. I would like to automatically navigate to the function right after I press M-.

How can I set this behaviour from my .emacs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun sm-find-tag ()
  (interactive)
  (find-tag (funcall (or find-tag-default-function
                         (get major-mode 'find-tag-default-function)
                         'find-tag-default))))
```